# Sling acces to JCR 'var' resource from java code

Tags: resources, sling, jcr

I am a begginer in `Sling` and I want find a way to get access and create file in `/var` resources of JCR.

I tried using `ResourceResolver` but I can not find the path as example below
`request.getResourceResolver().getResource("var");` it returns `null`.

Getting `resourceResolver` from `SlingHttpServletRequest` is a good way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, JCR paths should always start with a `/`. So your code was almost correct.

Change:

```
request.getResourceResolver().getResource("var");
```

To:

```
request.getResourceResolver().getResource("/var");
```

If your `ResourceResolver` has permissions to read `/var`, you will get a `Resource`. Otherwise, you get `null`. If you get the `ResourceResolver` from the `request`, the permissions depend on the permissions of the user doing the request.

> Getting resourceResolver from SlingHttpServletRequest is a good way to get it?

It depends. There is a lot to say about "where to get your `ResourceResolver`" from, but to make it simple:

> If you want to limit access to a resource based on a users permissions, you should get the `ResourceResolver` from a `request`. In all other situations, get the `ResourceResolver` from the `ResourceResolverFactory`.

The `ResourceResolverFactory` is its own rabbit hole. So I would point you to the documentation for that:

https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling9/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html